# Aggregate results in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database with 800+ different bars, clubs and restaurants across Australia.

I want to build a list of links for my website counting the number of different venues across different suburbs and primary categories.

Like this:

[Restaurants, Bowen Hills (15)](/bowen-hills/restaurents/)
[Restaurants, Dawes Point (6)](/dawes-point/restaurents/)
[Clubs, Sydney (138)](/clubs/bars/)

I could do it the hard way by first getting all venues. Then run a Venue.distinct('details.location.suburb') to get all the unique suburbs.

From here I could run subsequent queries to get the count for the number of venues in that particular suburb and category.

It will be a lot of calls though. There's got to be better way?

Can the Mongo aggregation framework help here?
It seems to be impossible to do this in a single query.

Here's the Venue model:

```
{ 
        "name" : "Johnny's Bar & Grill",  

        "meta" : {
            "category" : {
                "all" : [
                    "restaurant",
                    "bar"
                ], 
                "primary" : "restaurant"
            }
        }, 

        "details" : {
            "location" : {
                "streetNumber" : "180", 
                "streetName" : "abbotsford road", 
                "suburb" : "bowen hills", 
                "city" : "brisbane", 
                "postcode" : "4006", 
                "state" : "qld", 
                "country" : "australia"
            }, 
            "contact" : {
                "phone" : [
                    "(07) 5555 5555"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the prettified solution from BatScream that I ended up using:

```
Venue.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {

            _id: {
                primary: '$meta.category.primary',
                suburb: '$details.location.suburb',
                country: '$details.location.country',
                state: '$details.location.state',
                city: '$details.location.city'
            },

            count: {
                $sum: 1
            },

            type: {
                $first: '$meta.category.primary'
            }
        }
    },

    {
        $sort: {
            count: -1
        }
    },

    {
        $limit: 50
    },

        // Reshapes each document in the stream, such as by adding new fields or removing existing fields. For each input document, outputs one document.
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            type : '$type',
            location : '$_id.suburb',
            count: 1
        }
    }
],

function(err, res){
    next(err, res);
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a very useful and easily transformable output using the following aggregation operation.

- Group the records based on their country, category, state, city and
  suburb.
- Get the count of the records in each group.
- Obtain the type of the group from the first record of the group.
- Project the necessary fields.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":{"primary":"$meta.category.primary",
                "suburb":"$details.location.suburb",
                "country":"$details.location.country",
                "state":"$details.location.state",
                "city":"$details.location.city"},
         "count":{$sum:1},
         "type":{$first:"$meta.category.primary"}}},
{$sort:{"count":-1}},
{$project:{"_id":0,
           "type":"$type",
            "location":"$_id.suburb",
            "count":1}}
])
```

sample o/p:

```
{ "count" : 1, "type" : "restaurant", "location" : "bowen hills" }
```

Comment: Holy crap! That does EXACTLY what I want. It's perfect. I need to study Mongo aggregation. Thanks a millions - you just saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Could you also sort the results, so the highest counts were at the top at the list? At what about limiting the number of results?

Comment: I have edited my answer to accommodate the sort based on the count. what is the criteria for limiting. You could ask a separate question for that since it becomes quiet broad.

Comment: Thanks. I've already learned a lot here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/